# Silverlight sockets: mimic framework Bind, Listen and Accept methods?

Tags: c#, silverlight, sockets, tcp, silverlight-5.0

I have this .NET Framework C# class that practically acts as a wrapper for TCP connections around the [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/attbb8f5.aspx) class in the System.Net.Sockets namespace.

Recently I have migrated the API of this wrapper class to Silverlight, but because of the [limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) of the Socket class in Silverlight, as well as the normal trust restrictions with respect to avaiable ports, client access policy etc., I have only implemented network client support in my Silverlight version.

Now, with [Silverlight 5 (RC)](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/09/04/the-big-list-of-whats-new-or-improved-in-silverlight-5), it has become possible to apply elevated trust even for in-browser SL applications, which removes all the port and client access policy restrictions that I had to adhere to in SL 4.

My question is, if there is also a way to implement some kind of network server support in my SL wrapper class? More specifically, is there a way in Silverlight to mimic the Bind, Listen and Accept methods of the .NET Framework [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/attbb8f5.aspx) class?

To mimic Socket.Connect, I have used the [ConnectAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538102%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) method in the Silverlight [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/attbb8f5%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) class. Could something similar be done for the Bind/Listen/Accept methods using e.g. [Receive(From)Async](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receivefromasync%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)?

Thanks in advance.