# How can I get a Silverlight 4 client to connect to a windows service

Tags: .net, silverlight-4.0, windows-services

I have an existing window service. It does not use WCF and nor do I want it to. The windows service listens on a port and once a socket connects it starts publishing application status information every second.

I want to build a SilverLight application that can consume all the published information and update a display. I have come across plenty of articles that describe this for a web service or for a WCF service. I have stock standard executable running as a window service. Am I trying to do the impossible here.

Comment: Dear uriDium, I posted a similar question yesterday, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7490423/silverlight-sockets-mimic-framework-bind-listen-and-accept-methods. I do not have an answer to your question, but maybe some of the links can lead you in the desired direction.

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight has some support for using sockets directly. See [Working With Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on MSDN. Pay special attention to the part about security restrictions policy. If Silverlight runs in the sandbox (not OOB) you cannot connect to any random host on the network.